# How to use Curl to generate a public token in the backend with the plaid api without the front end?

Tags: plaid

I would like to be able to download transactions daily on my server using the plaid api. But according to plaid documentations the public/token/create has been deprecated. What I want to achieve is to be able to download transactions in the backend silently in my backend for a particular bank account. But, eventhough I succeeded in doing that in sandbox but it doesn't seem to be possible in production and development. Has anybody tried generate a public token exclusively from the backend with curl or other languages? if so, give some examples how I can achieve that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need an `public_token` to exchange for an `access_token` in order to make API calls, and it is not possible to get a `public_token` for a live (non-Sandbox) account without using Plaid Link (the UI component where the user enters their credentials).

However, because an `access_token` does not typically expire, you generally need to only get one once. So if you are just building a script for personal use, it is a perfectly viable workaround to set up the Plaid Quickstart to run against Development, walk through it to get an `access_token`, copy and paste that `access_token` to some secure location where it is available to your GUI-free script, and go from there.

(`/item/public_token/create` being deprecated is somewhat orthogonal to your problem -- that endpoint could never be used to create an initial public token, it could only be used to update a pre-existing public token if you had one that stopped working.)

Comment: Thank you! After banging my head around it for a few hours. This solution works perfectly! Thanks again!